# Expectation and bias of estimators for a given population

Tags: normal-distribution, moment-generating-functions, descriptive-statistics

I am brushing up on some statistics before undertaking a Machine Learning course, and I came across the concept of moments and expectation/bias and am completely lost. In particular I can't make heard or tail of the following question:

---

Consider the random sample $X_1,....X_n$ that is independently and identically distributed, for some population density $f_x$ with finite mean and a positive, non-infinite variance.

$\theta = E[X^2] = var(X) + (E[X])^2 = \sigma^2 + \mu^2 $

Consider the estimator:

$\hat\theta = \{ \frac {1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i(X_i+1)\} - \{\frac {1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\}^2$

Assume the observed values for the random sample are 3,8,11,12,19.

1. What is the corresponding observed value of $\hat\theta $?
2. Calculate the expectation and the bias of this estimator as functions of $\sigma$ and $\mu^2$

---

I believe question 1 to be simple enough, just a case of subbing the observed values from the sample into the formula:

$\hat\theta = \{ \frac {1}{5} (1 \times 2  \}(2 \times 3  \}(4 \times 5  \}(6 \times 7  \}(11 \times 12  \} - (\frac {1}{5}(1+2+4+6+11))^2$

$\hat\theta = 40.4 - 23.04 = 17.36 $

However I have no idea how I am supposed to calculated the expectation and bias in Question 2. Any insight or assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would use the mean squared error, where $E[\hat\theta]= Var(\hat\theta) + (E[\hat\theta]-\theta)^2  $ the estimator is said to be unbiased if $E[\hat\theta]= Var(\hat\theta)$ ,so
$(E[\hat\theta]-\theta)^2  $ is the bias

Comment: @minebeto666 im a little lost how to connect the formula for $\theta$ in the question, the calculated $\hat\theta$ and the mean squared error - can you share any insight into this?